# No title creation on first view

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I bounced into a problem when I was trying to create a title on the first view I created within my application.

At first, i hopped over all the push actions I had within my application and applied after this create.view screen a title as refered in the code under here

```
this.StembureauView = Ext.create('UtrechtStem.view.Stembureaulijst_View', {
                title: 'Stembureaulijst'
});
this.getMainnav().push(this.StembureauView);
```

this works fine, and I seem to have no problem with it. However, the first screen, so my main view, as loaded first view, doesnt accept the title statement.

```
    Ext.create('UtrechtStem.view.MainNav', {
         fullscreen: true, 
         title:'stembureau zoeker'
    });
```

if i add nicely behind the fullscreen statement a title statement, it wont accept it. (this is done outside sencha architect, cause appearantly i cant modify it within sencha artchitect) It just shows blank. I tried removing the toolbar, to see if that was the mistake, but it didnt. I tried addding manualyy outside Sench

Does anybody have a clue why it wont accept the title statement there and to see if there is a work arround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guess your class UtrechtStem.view.MainNav is inherited from the Ext.navigation.View. If yes, you can not set its title direct. Instead it borrow the active child's title.

Have a look at the [doc site](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-cfg-navigationBar)

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Thanks, it tried to grab the first child I had added (I had an extra toolbar under it) I moved it down and gave the component the title i wanted it to have. Cleared it up. THank you very much. I dont know how i read over that, cause that article in the documentation site I had actually open. I just mnissed it i guess. Thank you